# Самоих себя

Tags: семантика

Есть ли смысловая разница между **самоих себя** и *самих себя*? И вообще, откуда такая форма **самоих**?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Как я воспринимаю это слово?  Конечно, как книжное. Поэтому, если его используют в предложениях, описывающих обыденное, приземленное, это воспринимается как напыщенность, вычурность. (*Как защитить самоё себя)*  И даже в предложении *Юджа Ванг превосходит самое себя* оно мне кажется не совсем уместным. Возможно, было бы лучше  сказать *"превосходит (превзошла) саму себя".* 
Для меня слово "самоё" однозначно обозначает сущность.  **Человек нечаянная, прекрасная, мучительная попытка природы осознать самоё себя (В. М. Шукшин)**

Т.е. я не могу сказать, что *саму себя (самих себя)* тождественно *самоё себя (самоих себя)*. В первом случае слово сам служит для выделения возвратного местоимения: нарисуй себя - нарисуй сам себя, во втором означает суть, сущность: познай самоё себя - познай свою сущность, суть.

Повторю, что это моё, субъективное, восприятие слова. А примеры употребления слова взяты с просторов Интернета.

Answer (score 2):

Сейчас эта форма устаревшая и диалектная,употребляется как стилистическая фигура, а в старой грамматике было разграничение в употреблении местоимений сам и самый: первое относилось к названиям одушевленных предметов, второе — к названиям предметов неодушевленных. Отсюда сама и самоё (самоё себя =саму себя). А взялась форма из древнерусского языка, где это местоимение склонялось по твёрдому склонению прилагательных, сравните:

Множественное число

•   И. добрии добра?а добрь >

•   Р. добрыихъ

•   Д. добрыимъ

•   В. добрь > добра?а добрь >

•   Тв. добрыими

•   М. добрыихъ

Самоё -самои -самоих

Comment: В целом согласна. Но почему диалектная-то? В 80-е годы преподаватели университета очень активно использовали эту форму, особенно в курсе философии, психологии. Я понимаю, что форма устаревает, но диалектной она от этого не становится. Для меня после обучения в университете эта форма стала знаком, что говорится о чем-то сущностном, глубинном

Comment: @Ларf, может тогда подробнее напишите в ответе, как это слово воспринимаете вы. Мне крайне интересно узнать именно восприятие слова в современном языке, а не только исторический дискурс. Для чего эту форму используют ныне, для полушутливой напыщенности или наоборот для подчёркивания важности? А может вообще, что-то третье.

Answer (score 1):

"Самоё" и "самое" = одно, но... ...Глубинное, устаревшее - на вкус как бы одно, но... Нюансы...
Тож и "самоё" - похоже, что в него сама ирония, наряду с гримасами жизни, вселилась

Answer (score 1):

Немного мозг сломал на этом вопросе.

Сказать что САМОИХ - от САМОё не достаточно.

Дело в том, что есть целый пласт местоимений оканчивающихся на е/ё:

САМОё-САМОИ, ОНОЕ-ОНОИ, ТОЕ-ТОИ, СИЕ-СИИ, ИНОЕ-ИНЫЕ, ТО-ТЕ, СВОЯ-СВОЁ - в частном употреблении сохранилось только иное/иные, то-те, своё.

Причем они употреблялись параллельно с общеизвестными сами, оно, они, это, тот, свой и тд.

И все они значили не совсем тоже, что общеизвестные "аналоги".

Например окончание свой - это как твой. Я взял свой - я взял твой, возьми свой - возьми принадлежащий тебе. Я взял своя - я взял принадлежащий себе, он взял своя - он взял принадлежащий ему.

Или, например:

Ученики своя - по современному будет звучать как учеников своих - личных. В то время как свои употребляется когда идет обращение во втором лице - принадлежащие вам, а не лично кому-то.

То есть формы безличных местоимений были богаче.

Тут появляется вопрос, о том, что есть личность?

Дело в том, что в русском языке есть два противоположных значения личности, которые в итоге соединились в одном слове. Личность - маска, маска актера при игре роли, ролевая личность. И личность - сущность человека, истинная личность.

Если брать Юнга, то дело было так:

Есть личность - Эго и есть Подсознание(безличная сущность, связанная с архетипами, глубинными поведенческими моделями). Личность - это суть эгоизм, а подсознание то, что подсказывает естественное, верное - естественная сущность, нравственность.

Однако, Фрейд все переворачивает и говорит, что есть Бессознательное - ОНО, которое формируется через детские травмы и комплексы(никакое не Подсознание), так вот это бессознательное должно быть осмысленно Эго человека и подчиненного его Эго, чтобы развиться в Супер-Эго. Личность по Фрейду не данность, а результат развития. И будет ли это гармоничная личность или нарцисс/эгоист - это результат работы самоанализа/психоанализа или что выросло - то выросло. Эго осознает бессознательное, вытаскивая скелетов из шкафа.

Так вот. Русское слово САМО+ё - употреблялось для обозначение отношения к Архетипическое сознание(Юнга) или отношение Эго и ОНО(Фрейда), а не чему-то телесному или к чему-то объективному.

> Вы спрашиваете, кто мне дал право вас мучить, как я сохранил мое непрошенное влияние? Неужели в самом деле я и всегда я буду во всем виноват? Неужели во мне нет человеческого чувства и я вечно играю и собой, и другими! Спросите самое себя и судите сами!… М. В. Авдеев. Тамарин (1851)

Спросите не себя, а свою внутреннюю сущность - ОНО. Сам - это то, что можно пощупать, а САМОё - это то, что есть, но пощупать нельзя, ОНО щупает, его можно спросить.

> Она, может быть, бежала бы в полк или не знаю куда, если б она была мужчиной; но девушкой она бежала в самое себя... Герцен.

Сейчас бы перевели: она бежала внутрь/вглубь себя, замкнулась в себе. Но не она бежала в саму себя - бессмыслица.

> Эмилия сердилась на самое себя: несколько раз она хотела спросить молодого человека, где он был до обеда, но какая-то гордость заграждала ей уста... Бесстужев.

Внутренняя борьба Эмилии с самой собой - я переворачиваю. Истинные желания Эмилии - это самое, а "Эмилия"-ОНА(ОНО) сердилась на САМОё. Хотела сказать, но гордость(суть грех, эгоизм) заграждал ей уста, эгоистическая натура Эмилии сердилась на САМОё.

Также ё находит отражение в фразах с моё:

> Явилась дева; ярый смех
>
> Раздался дико; очи всех,
>
> Копыты, хоботы кривые,
>
> Хвосты хохлатые, клыки,
>
> Усы, кровавы языки,
>
> Рога и пальцы костяные,
>
> Все указует на нее,
>
> И все кричат: моё! моё!
>
> Моё! - сказал Евгений грозно...

Хотя говорил о душе Татьяны(Тать - отнимающий что-то, кстати говоря, Отнимающая у Яны(от Иоанн), отнимающая божью милость, крадущая божью милость). То есть Евгений(имеющий превосходство по роду εὖ γεγονώς ~ знатный, родовитый, правильно и род, евгеника туда же, продукт евгеники) это слова не от САМОё Евгения, а его ОНО победившего эгоизма, ОНО Евгения говорит МОё. А САМОё сказало бы СВОё - она своя.

Ладно, в общем как-то так.